# Branches for Testing and Production Environments on Git/Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using Git and Bitbucket to control version of my software.
Right now I have 2 origin branches in bitbucket: Testing and Master.

The Testing branch updates my local server automatically. And the master branch updates the production automatically.

I have a team with 5 developers, each one have the local branches: Testing and the Master.

The problem is: when a developer pushes to the testing/origin branch, the others developers are not being able to push their modifications because they're behind of testing/origin. I know that they can "git push -f" but **this overwrites the last commit** from other developers. And I know they need to *pull* before pushing, but when they pull, they're **getting the changes of others developers**, and that's not what I want. I need they work on their individual changes on the testing branch.

Any ideia on how can I solve this problem ?

*Sorry if u dont understand, english is not my first language...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you can simply have each of your developers create his own branch derived from the `testing` branch:

```
git checkout testing
git checkout -b my_testing
# work work work
git commit -m 'finished my work'
git push origin my_testing
```

At this point, each of your developers has created his own branch based on `testing`, completed and committed his work, and pushed his branch to Bitbucket.  Now he can create a *pull request* with the `testing` branch as a destination.  If the request gets approved, it can be merged into `testing` in Bitbucket.

After the merge completes, all the developer's work will now be in `testing`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a branching strategy similar to gitflow.  https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

The only way to achieve what you are looking for is for each dev to work on their own branch.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is for a developer to create a new branch(child branch) from Testing(parent branch) on the local machine and work on that. But note when the code is ready to push, the developer must switch to the parent branch(Testing) then pull all the latest from remote Testing.

After that they must merge the child branch to the parent branch **local** first. At this point, the developer may came across merge conflicts. At this time use tools like http://meldmerge.org/ to view the conflict and resolve them with the another developer that pushed the code. At last, your local Testing(Parent) branch is up to date and has no conflicts. So at this point the developer can push the Testing branch to remote.